# Javascript Unexpected identifier Function

Tags: javascript, zapier

I am working on a Zap to get information from a Webhook into Salesforce and in the case where a field is blank in the Webhook I am trying to replace a blank field with the characters "NA", but keep getting the following error:

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier Function (native) Domain. (/var/task/index.js:52:23) Domain.run (domain.js:228:14) module.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:51:5)

My code is as follows:

return { 
Secondary Presenter Fiirst Name: inputData.Secondary Presenter Fiirst Name.replace(/ /g,"NA"),
Secondary Presenter Last Name: inputData.Secondary Presenter Last Name.replace(/ /g,"NA"),
Secondary Presenter Title: inputData.Secondary Presenter Title.replace(/ /g,"NA")
}

I have tried replacing the / /g with /""/g and /" "/g but neither of those are working either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't encapsulating your strings correctly - try:

```
return {
  'Secondary Presenter Fiirst Name': inputData['Secondary Presenter Fiirst Name'].replace(/ /g, "NA"),
  'Secondary Presenter Last Name': inputData['Secondary Presenter Last Name'].replace(/ /g,"NA"),
  'Secondary Presenter Title': inputData['Secondary Presenter Title'].replace(/ /g,"NA")
}
```

Note - I fixed some formatting but the big deal is the proper usage of `'` to encapsulate the strings and keys.

Comment: New error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined theFunction (eval at <anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:52:23), <anonymous>:13:82) eval (eval at <anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:52:23), <anonymous>:28:20) Domain.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:53:5) Domain.run (domain.js:228:14) module.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:51:5)

Comment: Also, these are fields not strings